# How to execute the print command in C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

At the beginning of [this document](http://www.labeljoy.com/support/how-to/integrate-software-with-labeljoy/), it says you can right-click on a file and print from there. Now my question is, how do I print using C#? I can call the executable and give it the print command and the file, and it prints. I can call the file directly, and it opens. But how do I call the file, and tell it to print?

Here is my current code, which requires knowing where the program is.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = PathToProgram;
psi.Arguments = "/P \"" + PathToFile + "\"";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Small link fail there...

Comment: Your code looks like it does exactly what you need. It calls the program and tells it to print the file. I don't understand what else you want. What do you mean by "call the file"? I only understand calling functions or programs.

Comment: By "calling the file" I understand calling the Shell Print function directly: ShellExecute(NULL, "print", PathToFile, NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);

Comment: Thank you celerno! That makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got it. This is exactly what I was looking for. Notice the Verbs property. It lists the different options you have to work with for that program.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = Program.appdata.PathToBillItemsLabels;
//Break. psi.Verbs = { "Open", "Print" };
psi.Verb = "Print";
Process.Start(psi).WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
```

You must change the property to TRUE to work properly. 
Regards

Comment: Agreed with @AthomSfere - If you don't have the time, patience or desire to offer an explanation of your answer, don't answer.  This gives absolutely no feedback to the OP as to why he would want to change that value.

Comment: Actually, the code I posted works perfectly well as is. However, I think I read elsewhere that for the code I gave in my answer to work, it must be true (which is default).